# VSTS Assign following of a Task

Tags: azure-devops, task

Is there a way to set the people who are following a task?

I have Stakeholders who are not creating the user story, but I want to assign them as followers.

Answer (score 0):

The stakeholder can open the work item and click on the "Follow" button:

[image]

Now he will get notifications about the work item.

You can't assign followers to work items, only the user itself can.

There is an open User Voice for this request, you can vote up:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13885038-assign-followers-to-a-work-item

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way but you have to be an Admin.  You can create a Notification for that stake holder.  See Administer Alerts for a Project here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/boards/queries/alerts-and-notifications?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer.